# TypeError when trying to convert Python 2.7 code to Python 3.4 code

Tags: python

I am having issues converting the code below which was written for `Python 2.7` to code compatible in `Python 3.4`. I get the error `TypeError: can't concat bytes to str` in the line `outfile.write(decompressedFile.read())`. So I replaced the line with `outfile.write(decompressedFile.read().decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))`, but this resulted in the error same error.

```
import os
import gzip
try:
    from StirngIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
baseURL = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file="
filename = "data/irt_euryld_d.tsv.gz"
outFilePath = filename.split('/')[1][:-3]

response = urllib.request.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = StringIO()
compressedFile.write(response.read().decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))

compressedFile.seek(0)

decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb') 

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read()) #Error
```

Comment: Doesn't the write mode have to be `'wb'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `GzipFile` needs to wrap a bytes-oriented file object, but you're passing a `StringIO`, which is text-oriented.  Use [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead:

```
from io import BytesIO  # Works even in 2.x

# snip

response = urllib.request.urlopen(baseURL + filename)
compressedFile = BytesIO()  # change this
compressedFile.write(response.read())  # and this

compressedFile.seek(0)

decompressedFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedFile, mode='rb') 

with open(outFilePath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(decompressedFile.read().decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
    # change this too
```

Comment: Thank You. But I now get the Error `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface` in the line `compressedFile.write(response.read().decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))`

Comment: @user131983: Fixed, see edit.  You could probably just do `compressedFile=BytesIO(response.read())`...