# From gzip to json to dataframe to csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, gzip, urllib

I am trying to get some data from an open API:

```
https://data.brreg.no/enhetsregisteret/api/enheter/lastned
```

but I am having difficulties understanding the different type of objects and the order the conversions should be in. Is it `strings` to `bytes`, is it `BytesIO` or `StringIO`, is it `decode('utf-8)` or `decode('unicode)` etc..?

So far:

```
url_get = 'https://data.brreg.no/enhetsregisteret/api/enheter/lastned'


with urllib.request.urlopen(url_get) as response:
    encoding = response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
    compressed_file = io.BytesIO(response.read())
    decompressed_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_file)
```

and now is where I am stuck, how should I write the next line of code?

```
json_str = json.loads(decompressed_file.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

My workaround is if I write it as a json file then read it in again and do the transformation to df then it works:

```
with io.open('brreg.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(decompressed_file.read())

with open(f_path, encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    d = json.load(fin)

df = json_normalize(d)

with open('brreg_2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fout:
    fout.write(df.to_csv())
```

I found many SO posts about it, but I am still so confused. This first one explains it quite good, but I still need some spoon feeding.

[Python 3, read/write compressed json objects from/to gzip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450065/python-3-read-write-compressed-json-objects-from-to-gzip-file)

[TypeError when trying to convert Python 2.7 code to Python 3.4 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992083/typeerror-when-trying-to-convert-python-2-7-code-to-python-3-4-code)

[How can I create a GzipFile instance from the “file-like object” that urllib.urlopen() returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204604/how-can-i-create-a-gzipfile-instance-from-the-file-like-object-that-urllib-url)

[JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)

Comment: What issues do you get with your code as it stands? It looks to me like you're missing a .decompress() on the GZipFile object

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Sorry, this is the traceback I get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me using the `decompress` function rather than the `GZipFile` class to decompress the file, but not sure why yet...

```
import urllib.request
import gzip
import io
import json

url_get = 'https://data.brreg.no/enhetsregisteret/api/enheter/lastned'


with urllib.request.urlopen(url_get) as response:
    encoding = response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
    compressed_file = io.BytesIO(response.read())
    decompressed_file = gzip.decompress(compressed_file.read())
    json_str = json.loads(decompressed_file.decode('utf-8'))
```

**EDIT**, in fact the following also works fine for me which appears to be your exact code... 
(**Further edit**, turns out it's not quite your exact code because your final line was outside the with block which meant `response` was no longer open when it was needed - see comment thread)

```
import urllib.request
import gzip
import io
import json

url_get = 'https://data.brreg.no/enhetsregisteret/api/enheter/lastned'


with urllib.request.urlopen(url_get) as response:
    encoding = response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
    compressed_file = io.BytesIO(response.read())
    decompressed_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_file)
    json_str = json.loads(decompressed_file.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected now! I've learned that life is too short to ponder why things work, since there are plenty of things that do not ;)

Comment: Ah, so in my code the last line was outside the with statement, but I don't see why that should have been a problem. Anyway, ref the above quote.

Comment: That sounds plausible as the cause of the issue. Certainly GzipFile just acts as a 'wrapper' for the underlying file object and I can imagine that BytesIO does the same. In that case all these lines depend upon 'response' still being open.